# How to convert string of numbers into int array in java

Tags: java, string

I have an input String of "0102030405" how can I split this number by two so that it would have an output of `String[] ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05")`.

Comment: Can you show another example?

Comment: You have to take substring of above string by the multiple of two.

Comment: @limbo you can see 'java' tag to detect the language :P

Comment: @Khan it was added recently, I checked it before and all it had was string

Comment: I'm using java as my language sir.

Comment: Oops! Sorry @limbo

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String a = "0102030405";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split("(?<=\\G.{2})")));
```

Comment: I tried this code is work if i code it in eclipse an it gave an output of [12, 23, 56] but when i tried it at android studio it gave me an output of [12, 2345] what is the reason for this sir and what is the remedy?

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "0102030405";

    String[] output = new String[input.length()/2];

    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i+=2){
        output[k++] = input.substring(i, i+2);
    }

    for(String s:output){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like reading each two characters from a string.
This could be solved by: `"(?<=\\G.{2})"`

But I think a cleaner solution is this:

```
string.substring(startStringInt, endStringInt);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String part : splitString("0102030405", 2)) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> splitString(String string, int numberOfChars) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i += numberOfChars)
        {
            result.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(string.length(), i + numberOfChars)));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        HelloWorld h1 = new HelloWorld();
        String a = "0102030405";
        System.out.println(h1.getSplitString(a));
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getSplitString(String stringToBeSplitted) {
        char[] charArray = stringToBeSplitted.toCharArray();
        int stringLength = charArray.length;
        ArrayList<String> outPutArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i <= stringLength-2; i+=2){
            outPutArray.add("" + charArray[i] + charArray[i+1]);
        }
        return outPutArray;
     }
}
```

Here the String is first split into a char array. Then using a for loop two digits are concatenated and put into a ArrayList to return. If you need an Array to return you can change the return type to String[] and in the return statement change it to

```
outPutArray.toArray(new String[outPutArray.size()];
```

If you insert a string has odd number of characters last character will be omitted. Change the loop condition to fix that.